# I am geting unsupported operand type(s) for | 'str' and 'bool' in the below python3 code and i cant understand why?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'bool'
I have attached the screenshot below

```
train = train.drop(((train[train['pickup_latitude']<-90])|(train[train['pickup_latitude']>90])).index, axis=0)
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/madhurisivalenka/cleansing-eda-modelling-lgbm-xgboost-starters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a mistake in the use of parenthesis. fix:

```py
train = train.drop((train[(train['pickup_latitude']<-90) | (train['pickup_latitude']>90)]).index, axis=0)
```

Notice the format is `train[complex condition]` and not `train[condition1] | train[condition2]`, as "train[]" returns some type which you can not use "|" simply.

An easier way to eliminate undesired values:

`train=train.loc[(abs(train['pickup_latitude']))<=90]`

it uses `.loc` instead of `drop`, means it acts on desired data rather then eliminate "bad" data. Instead of checking complex condition, just check on absolute value of column.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

mask=np.logical_or(train['pickup_latitude'].lt(-90), train['pickup_latitude'].gt(90))

#or even better:
mask=train['pickup_latitude'].abs().gt(90)

train.drop(mask.loc[mask].index, inplace=True)
```